# messages keeps asking for password for jabber account

Tags: macos, messages, high-sierra

Apple messages keeps asking for password every time I try to log in to my jabber account.

The password is correctly saved in the keychain (in fact I just go and copy it from there each time). *Save Password to Keychain* is of course always checked.

I can not find *Keychain First Aid* in High Sierra, it seems it has been removed. I tried creating a new login keyring, removing the jabber account and re-adding it (both from *Messages* and from *System Preferences*). I also tried adding `imagent` and `Messages.app` to the authorized applications list for that Keychain entry (as suggested [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/messages-keeps-asking-me-for-password.1452661/)).

The only weird thing I encountered is that when the problem started I had two entries in keychain for that password. Now I only have one, no matter what I do.

I also tried resetting messages by renaming away `~/Library/Messages` but this led to a "message database is upgrading, please try again later" prompt.

It seems that while creating a new account saves the password in the keychain as it should, *Messages* fails to read it.

Comment: This solution worked for me: https://discussions.apple.com/message/32744059#32744059

Comment: Thanks. 5 hours of searching didn't yield this for some reason. Why don't you create an answer here so I can accept it?

Comment: It's too short for answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This solution worked for me:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/32744059#32744059

> After running a comparison with a working version (on Sierra 10.12.6) it looks like the solution (at least for me) is to change the **Where** value that gets generated on sign in from what gets populated when adding an account in High Sierra **com.apple.account.jabber.password** to **Jabber**
>
> In order to make this change follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open Keychain Access
> 2. Search for com.apple.account.jabber.password
> 3. Double click it to open the attributes prompt
> 4. In the **Where** field (fourth one down) you should see **com.apple.account.jabber.password**
> 5. Replace all text in that field with **Jabber**
> 6. Click Save Changes
>
> After making this change the first launch of messages asked me to allow permission to access keychain. After doing so any subsequent open of messages works as expected.

Comment: I had the same problem and changed the where in keychain to jabber and the problem was solved... many thanks

Answer (score 3):

I get the same error. Here is my fix

Open Keychain Access
Search for com.apple.account.jabber.password
Double click it to open the attributes prompt
In the "Account" field iMessage feed automatically   "xxx.xxx@gmail.com@talk.google.com"
Replace all text in that field with only "xxx.xxx@gmail.com"
Click Save Changes

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem repeatedly. When I looked into the Jabber keychain attributes, I selected "show password" and saw that the stored password was incorrect... a very old password that I had used on that account a few years ago. I manually updated it to use the current correct password, and now the problem seems to have disappeared. It seems that the password that I had been typing upon launching Messages app in wasn't being written to the keychain, so at least manually updating the password works around the problem.